# How to check what part of emacs overrides a variable

Tags: debugging, emacs

currently I'm struggling with creating a new C indentation style for a project I'm working on. This I did this:

```
(c-add-style "ck-style"
             '("bsd"
               (c-auto-align-backslashes . nil)
               (c-basic-offset . 4)
               (c-offsets-alist . ((case-label . +)
                                   (label . -)
                                   (statement-case-open . +)))
               (fill-column . 78)
               (indent-tabs-mode . t)
               (tab-width . 4)))

(defun ck-init-c ()
  (if (string-match "/project/" buffer-file-name)
        (c-set-style "ck-style")
      (c-set-style "bsd")))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'ck-init-c)
```

I also added debug `(message)` calls into the hook showing the value of `c-indentation-style` and in the hook it definitely has the right value. But when I check in the buffer, the value for `c-indentation-style` is set back to `"bsd"`. Is there a way to check which part of the initialization is causing this? Something like a watch expression in GDB?

Comment: You might find [directory variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) an easier way to do this.  Just put a `.dir-locals.el` in your project folder with the settings that you want.  It acts (kind of) like a folder-scoped `init.el`.

Comment: @harpo nice, didn't know about directory variables, yet. Thanks for the pointer! But for debugging purposes it would still be nice to know an answer.

Comment: @harpo Your remark made me wonder if there is something like that in the project tree already. And yes, there is: `(c-file-style . "bsd")` was set in the .dir-locals.el. So this is why my `c-set-style` got overwritten. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe usage of c-add-style is wrong. Seems you are adding "ck-style" not "bsd"(?)

Comment: @AndreasRöhler I was setting `(c-set-style "ck-style")` in my init scripts. This got overwritten by `.dir-locals.el` with `"bsd"` as I noticed after the hint from @harpo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a mechanism for what you're describing.

I suppose in principle you could use a `defadvice` on `setq`, but the manual [advises against](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) advising primitives, while pointing out that it is not 100% effective:

> Unless you know what you are doing, do not advise a primitive (see
>   What Is a Function). Some primitives are used by the advice mechanism;
>   advising them could cause an infinite recursion. Also, many primitives
>   are called directly from C code. Calls to the primitive from Lisp code
>   will take note of the advice, but calls from C code will ignore the
>   advice.

And `setq` is in fact used by `defadvice`.

In other words, variable assignment is too low-level to hook by ordinary means (*viz*, elisp).